# How to loop all the values of two imbricated CSV files with JMeter?

Tags: loops, csv, jmeter

I have two csv files `keys.csv` and `dates.csv` with the following content:

**keys.csv**

```
A
B
```

**dates.csv**

```
01/01/2019
02/01/2019
```

I want to pass the combination of those two files to a sampler. This sampler should receive the following values in this order:

```
  A 01/01/2019
  A 02/01/2019
  B 01/01/2019
  B 02/01/2019
```

Here is what I tried:

```
Thread Group (Nb of thread:1 - Ramp: 1 - Loop: 1)
  > CSV Data Set Config (keys.csv)
         Recycle on EOF ? True
     Stop thread on EOF ? False

  > CSV Data Set Config (dates.csv)
         Recycle on EOF ? True
     Stop thread on EOF ? False

  > JSR223 Sampler
      log.info("{} {}", vars.get("key") ,  vars.get("date"));
```

Here is what I get:

```
A 01/01/2019
```

I tried also While and Loop controllers without success.

**JMeter 5.2.1**

Comment: Do you only 2 rows in each csv?

Comment: @ararar My real CSV files have much more lines 16k+ in the first one and 365 in the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for 2 nested [Loop Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) like:

- Loop Controller with number of loops defined by the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

  ```
  ${__groovy(new File('keys.csv').readLines().size(),)}
  ```

  [image]

  - [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) with the following configuration:

    [image]

    - Another Loop Controller again with __groovy() function:

      ```
      {__groovy(new File('dates.csv').readLines().size(),)}
      ```

      [image]

      - Your JSR223 Sampler

        - CSV Data Set Config with the following setup:

          [image]

Overview and demo:

[image]

Full script just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.2.1">
    <hashTree>
        <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
            <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel"
                         testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
        </TestPlan>
        <hashTree>
            <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
                <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel"
                             testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
            </ThreadGroup>
            <hashTree>
                <LoopController guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller"
                                enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">true</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">
                        ${__groovy(new File(&apos;keys.csv&apos;).readLines().size(),)}
                    </stringProp>
                </LoopController>
                <hashTree>
                    <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config"
                                enabled="true">
                        <stringProp name="filename">keys.csv</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="variableNames">key</stringProp>
                        <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">false</boolProp>
                        <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
                        <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
                        <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
                        <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
                        <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
                    </CSVDataSet>
                    <hashTree/>
                    <LoopController guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller"
                                    enabled="true">
                        <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">true</boolProp>
                        <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">
                            ${__groovy(new File(&apos;dates.csv&apos;).readLines().size(),)}
                        </stringProp>
                    </LoopController>
                    <hashTree>
                        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="JSR223 Sampler"
                                       enabled="true">
                            <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
                            <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
                            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
                            <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
                            <stringProp name="script">log.info(&quot;{} {}&quot;, vars.get(&quot;key&quot;) , vars.get(&quot;date&quot;))</stringProp>
                        </JSR223Sampler>
                        <hashTree>
                            <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config"
                                        enabled="true">
                                <stringProp name="filename">dates.csv</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="variableNames">date</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
                                <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
                                <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
                            </CSVDataSet>
                            <hashTree/>
                        </hashTree>
                    </hashTree>
                </hashTree>
                <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector"
                                 testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
                    <objProp>
                        <name>saveConfig</name>
                        <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                            <time>true</time>
                            <latency>true</latency>
                            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                            <success>true</success>
                            <label>true</label>
                            <code>true</code>
                            <message>true</message>
                            <threadName>true</threadName>
                            <dataType>true</dataType>
                            <encoding>false</encoding>
                            <assertions>true</assertions>
                            <subresults>true</subresults>
                            <responseData>false</responseData>
                            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                            <xml>false</xml>
                            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
                            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                            <bytes>true</bytes>
                            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
                            <url>true</url>
                            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
                            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
                        </value>
                    </objProp>
                    <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
                </ResultCollector>
                <hashTree/>
            </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: Why do you put the last 'CSV Data Set Config' under 'JSR223 Sampler' ?

Comment: 1. Because I can. 2. I prefer to limit the [scope of JMeter test elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) to the necessary minimum.